# Software Requirements Specification for Reports

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting, specifications

Reports, generally, have the following components:

- Report title
- Physical location (repository, network drive, or web server file system)
- Parameters (hidden and user-supplied)
- Query (SQL)
- Security (roles and authorization)
- Formatting and layout (column order, static text, and images)

Q.1. What else would you want to read in a technical specification before you can begin developing the report?

Q.2. What software would you use to draft the report's design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Q1 - what are you using your technical spec for?  I'd add a report objective to the spec.  The most important bit is what the report needs to convey:  who is going to be using the report, and what information will help them make easier / quicker decisions.

On Q2 - Crystal is great for building reports - although recently I've been using the open-source birt plugin as I like the integration with eclipse.  (I haven't used crystal's eclipse plug-in or SSRS).

Depends a bit on your requirements:

- Are you looking for a commercial package, or open-source?
- If you're selecting a new system, what will the people who will be creating the reports be most comfortable with?
- Do you need training or commercial support?
- What sort of data sources are you using?

You might refer to these for Q2:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485901/what-reporting-platform-do-you-prefer

[Compare SQL Server Reporting Services to Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168427/compare-sql-server-reporting-services-to-crystal-reports)

[Which Reporting technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115283/which-reporting-technology)

Comment: Excel is great for quick reports - and has the added benefit of using mock data & making report-producible charts.  Nice too, as you can have a mock report in one sheet and details in another.